# Printing a list in a for loop with titles connected to each value

Tags: python, python-3.x

The for loop is giving this error, `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`

```py
for (item,price,quan) in shoplist:
    print('Item:',item, 'Price:$',price, 'Quantity:',quan)
```

want it to look like

item: milk     price: $1.00     quantity: 4
Item: apple    price: $1.00     quantity: 5

Comment: How are the values formatted in `shoplist`?

Comment: they are appended like shoplist.append(['Quantity:',quan])

Comment: if so, you might need to append to shopList:
shopList.append((item, price, quan))  so that you can then do the for loop like you have it and have 3 items to unpack

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]